# ¿Cómo escuchar un TextView en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo un Login, quisiera escuchar un TextView, un Cardview y un Editext para que funcionen como botones. 
Gracias.

Comment: ¿ porque no agregas el código o lo que has tratado? Revisar [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu método `onCreateView` obtén tu text_view o lo que desees y asígnale una función para ejecutar al dar click.

```
tu_text_view.setOnClickListener(tu_funcion);
```

fuera del metodo declara tu función

```
private View.OnClickListener tu_funcion = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

//todo lo que deseas que haga

        }
    };
```

Comment: Gracias Kevin Puscán!